# Forge 1.11.2 wont install

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to install forge 1.11.2 to run a mod that I made.
When I run the installer(.jar) than it gives me this error:

> These libraries failed to download. Try again.
> org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-library_2.11:1.0.2
> org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1:1.0.2

[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxRLj.png)

Also, there is a log file that appears when i run it and and this is the contents:

```
Considering library net.minecraftforge:forge:1.11.2-13.20.1.2588: Not Downloading {Wrong Side}
Considering library net.minecraft:launchwrapper:1.12: Not Downloading {Wrong Side}
Considering library org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.0.3: Not Downloading {Wrong Side}
Considering library jline:jline:2.13: Not Downloading {Wrong Side}
Considering library com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.3.3
Considering library com.typesafe:config:1.2.1
Considering library org.scala-lang:scala-actors-migration_2.11:1.1.0
Considering library org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.1
Considering library org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-library_2.11:1.0.2
Checking "C:\Users\mynamehere\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\scala-lang\plugins\scala-continuations-library_2.11\1.0.2\scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar" internal checksums
    checksums.sha1 was not found, validation failed
Downloading library org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-library_2.11:1.0.2
Trying unpacked library org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-library_2.11:1.0.2
Checking "C:\Users\mynamehere\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\scala-lang\plugins\scala-continuations-library_2.11\1.0.2\scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar" internal checksums
    checksums.sha1 was not found, validation failed
File not found in installer archive: /maven/org/scala-lang/plugins/scala-continuations-library_2.11/1.0.2/scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar
Considering library org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1:1.0.2
Checking "C:\Users\mynamehere\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\scala-lang\plugins\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1\1.0.2\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar" internal checksums
    checksums.sha1 was not found, validation failed
Downloading library org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1:1.0.2
Trying unpacked library org.scala-lang.plugins:scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1:1.0.2
Checking "C:\Users\mynamehere\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\scala-lang\plugins\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1\1.0.2\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar" internal checksums
    checksums.sha1 was not found, validation failed
File not found in installer archive: /maven/org/scala-lang/plugins/scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1/1.0.2/scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar
Considering library org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1
Considering library org.scala-lang:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.1
Considering library org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.1
Considering library org.scala-lang:scala-swing_2.11:1.0.1
Considering library org.scala-lang:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.2
Considering library lzma:lzma:0.0.1: Not Downloading {Wrong Side}
Considering library net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.6: Not Downloading {Wrong Side}
Considering library java3d:vecmath:1.5.2
Considering library net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:3.0.3
```

My friend tried to install forge 1.11.2 but he got the same error

I am able to install forge 1.12.2 and 1.16.4. I have looked all over the internet for solutions and no one seems to have my exact problem.

Thanks!

:)

Comment: Scala continuation library seems to be missing a `checkaums.sha1`.

Comment: Thank you, any suggestions on how to fix it?